# Bot Framework channels, Oops. Something went wrong

Tags: facebook, botframework, bots, channel, facebook-messenger

I finished my bot in NodeJS, unfortunately, I’m having some issues when I try to connect it with some channels.
I tried to link it with Messenger and Microsoft Teams but when I launch the Bot I receive this message : “Oops. Something went wrong!” without any explanation.

But when I use the bot on my local environment, on the Azure environment or in an iFrame, it works perfectly.

Did I miss something?

Tanks a lot,

Comment: Is there somewhere that is capturing or logging more detailed error output? That would help other people when trying to answer this question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any idea where I can find any log about this connection attempt

Comment: When I go to Azure and check the warning messages I have this one for Facebook : Failed to validate incoming Facebook message. Make sure your FacebookAppSecret is entered correctly.

Comment: So did you checked your "FacebookAppSecret" in Bot Channel Registration? :)

Comment: Yes of course and I'm sure it's the correct one.
Is it possible the problem with the bot linked to others services due to the Azure Subscription?

Comment: If this is v4, have you updated your .bot file with a 'production' endpoint?

Comment: Do I need to add a specific Facebook endpoint?
I have my localhost endpoint and the https://blablabla.azurewebsites.net/api/messages

Comment: No, but you do have to make sure that the endpoints are named "development" (for the localhost one) and "production" (for the azure one).

Comment: Yes that’s correct. Is it possible to have this issue because of the azure susbscription?

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue in Teams as well or just in the Facebook channel?